# Unable to create a WAF2 gateway in azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

On the final stage of creating a WAF2 gateway, there is an error with code "ApplicationGatewaySslCertificateTooBig" and message "Data too big for certificate".

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of the PFX file is 16384.

It could be caused by root or intermediate certifcates being included in the PFX file. If so remove them so that the size is less than 16384.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I remove them?

Comment: See: https://serverfault.com/questions/848939/how-to-remove-the-ca-root-certificate-from-a-pfx-file-in-windows